# How can I download my Google API key as PEM file?

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to do a simple python script that pulls data from Google BigQuery. I've found many posts and google documents on Bigquery, but I've yet to have any success.  My current problem is that I need to read my API key from a PEM file, but I can't find any way to download my API key from the google dev console.  All I can do is copy/paste the text.

Comment: FWIW, I'm following this example:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization?hl=en#service-accounts-server

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new client Id with a type of "service account" this will download a new p12 file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Why do the docs say to use "installed application" to run a command line script that uses the api, if in fact I need to select "service account"?

Comment: I'm guessing the docs have not yet been updated from referencing [code.google.com/apis/console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect) to reference [cloud.google.com/console](https://cloud.google.com/console/project).