# PHP and Google API (BigQuery to be Specific)

Tags: php, google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

I am currently trying to develop some sort of a web app and I need it to be able to execute queries on a table that has over ~50,000,000 Rows.
I thought about using Google BigQuery for this matter but I am having problems using their API.
I've searched the whole internet for the past 3 hours and I couldn't find a way to get an authentication and execute a query with **PHP only**. For authentication I found a way using javascript but that will not be good for me. I need it to be **server sided only**.
The whole php google api documention seems outdated for me.
Thanks in advanced, Sagi.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries

Comment: @cmorrissey the exact library I was trying use, with no success.
I'm new to Google API.. :(

Comment: it gives you an auth example here ... https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: what server are you using? for any server you can download a pkey certificate for auth, while on GCE it's even easier

Comment: @FelipeHoffa The hosting is at GoDaddy, does it help?

Comment: ok, you will need to download a pkey certificate for the answer below to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607896/how-can-i-download-my-google-api-key-as-pem-file

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Hey, thanks for the answer. Could you please explain how can I get the service token file location or whether or not I need to create one myself?

Comment: see the link on my previous comment, you need to download that file

Comment: Im getting this error:
Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Invalid token format'
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code that works for us:

```
session_start();

define('PROJECT_ID', 'edited');
define('DATASET_ID', 'edited');
define('API_KEY', 'edited');

$client_id = 'edited';
$service_account_name = 'edited';
$key_file_location = '.ssh/privatekey-bigquery.p12';
$service_token_file_location = 'bigquery_current_service_token.json';

set_include_path("google-api-php/src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'google-api-php/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php/src/Google/Service/Bigquery.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
//$client->setDeveloperKey(API_KEY);

if (!is_file($service_token_file_location)) {
    if (!is_writable($service_token_file_location)) {
        @chmod($service_token_file_location, 0777);
        if (!is_writable($service_token_file_location)) {
            die('Service token file is not writable: ' . $service_token_file_location);
        }
    }
    file_put_contents($service_token_file_location, '');
} else {
    if (!is_writable($service_token_file_location)) {
        @chmod($service_token_file_location, 0777);
        if (!is_writable($service_token_file_location)) {
            die('Service token file is not writable: ' . $service_token_file_location);
        }
    }
}
$service_token = @file_get_contents($service_token_file_location);
if (!empty($service_token)) {
    $client->setAccessToken($service_token);
}
if (!file_exists($key_file_location)) {
    die('Key file is missing: ' . $key_file_location);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name, array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
        ), $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$service_token = $client->getAccessToken();
file_put_contents($service_token_file_location, $service_token);

// start using $client
```

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for the reply. May I ask what is the meaning of the variable $service_token_file_location? do I need to create the file myself?